# Chat application in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, chat, aws-appsync

I am looking to work on real-time chat application in a serverless architecture.

I am new to AWS so did some research on it but I found may option to do so.

Like:

1. app sync
2. WebSocket
3. elasticache redis

I am a bit confused about which I should go with.

I am looking for a cost-effective(**low charges**) setup for my app.

Comment: You might want to have a look at AWS AppSync https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-a-serverless-real-time-chat-application-with-aws-appsync/